# Calling a Javascript function after a partial page redirect

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I've got the following button:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!saveDeliveryRow}"  onComplete="saveComplete();"/>
```

This calls the following method on the controller :

```
public PageReference saveDelivery() { 
    upsert RightsTrackerListDelivery;
    return null;
}
```

However my problem is, the saveComplete() function in the button's onComplete event isn't fired. I was expecting it to perform the controller action and then afterwards enter the onComplete event.

If I put `onComplete="alert('test');"` then the alert will pop up **before** the page redirects. Is there any way to call a function like this?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this with the following:

Instead of using `action="{!saveDeliveryRow}"` in my commandLink/button, I created an action function linking to the method.

I then added the `onComplete="saveComplete"` event to the action function, and it works as expected.